# KVM/libvirt: How to disable clock sync for guests?

Tags: kvm, libvirt

is there any possibility to completely disable the clock synchronization for a guest virtual machine? The VM is disconnected from the network but retrieves the current time from the KVM host.

After deleting the line:

```
<clock offset='utc'>
```

from the virtual machine's definition file, the line is automatically recreated. Redhat's documentation just handles with the possible offset attributes, but unfortunately not how to disable time sync (Maybe it's not possible?).

Thanks for any advices!

Answer (score 3):

When a guest is booted QEMU needs to initialize the BIOS clock to some value. There's a choice of UTC, localtime (ie UTC adjusted to current timezone), an alternate timezone, or an offset relative to UTC. There's no way to disable BIOS clock initialization altogether. Possible options are described in more detail at http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsTime